# Is calling someone "tonto" offensive?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, significado, insultos

Both [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#en/es/silly) and [Spanishdict.com](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/silly) translate *silly* as *tonto*.  However, both as translate [*dumb*](https://translate.google.com/#en/es/dumb) as [*tonto*](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/dumb) also.  I find this hard to understand because *silly* and *dumb* are not synonymous in English, and notably calling someone silly in English is generally fun and playful, whereas calling someone dumb in English is an insult.

How should I understand this?  Is it completely context-driven?  Is there a safer word for *silly* for a novice to use to ensure it is not taken offensively?

Comment: It always depends on the context... but in general, do not say _tonto_ to someone until you know him/her well.

Comment: It is exactly the same as calling someone "fool". Sometimes is offensive and sometimes it is not.

Comment: 'Tonta' I think is a playful word because my ex-sister-in-law calls me 'tonta'. I don't think she is calling me out of my name.

Comment: Yes, it is context driven. You got that right. Fool in English is always offensive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It actually depends on the context, and also depends on intonation a lot.  However, I think most of the times we use it (in Spain) in an offensive way, it comes always with some emphasize that makes clear we're talking seriously. If you say it laughing in a non so-serious context it is difficult to offend someone or get misunderstood.

Here in Spain you could use ['bobo'](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5i6Gnjj) as a translation for silly, since 'bobo' is even more playful. However, it can be offensive too, like you can see [here](http://www.marca.com/2013/12/09/futbol/equipos/valencia/1386586266.html) and [here](http://m.noticiasdenavarra.com/2016/01/29/deportes/futbol/neymar-manolo-lama-habla-mierda-eres-bobo), but is really not so common.

Answer (score 3):

En Perú sería una ofensa traducirlo "tonto".  Más bien decimos "**disforzado**" lo cual se aplica a alguien quien **se hace el payaso** o está haciendo reír a alguien.

Comment: Bienvenida, Gabriela.  Interesante este regionalismo.  También "se hace el payaso" que mencionaste funciona bien, yo creo de manera universal.